# Zoom image until it fits ImageView Completely

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5

I have a simple `UIImageView` and an image. I want to fit the image in that `UIImageView` but I don't want the image aspect ratio to change and I also don't want any dead spaces. ( black bars on the sides etc') I don't care if the image is zoomed in all the way as long as those 2 rules are applied.

Is there a build in setting for that? I tried all the `Scale To Fill` and `Aspect Fill` etc' but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

For example: `UIImageView` is 300x300
image is 200x250. The image will zoom in until all the areas of the `UIImageView` are filled.

Comment: Aspect Fill does this for you. If it "is not working" then you are not using it properly. Can you post some code.

Comment: There's no code involved. I'm using the IB .Aspect Fill goes out of the bounds of the `UIImageView` to keep its aspect. That's not what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, in that case then tick the box that says "clips subviews" on the image view inspector.

Comment: Great. Now I feel stupid. Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: No worries :D Have posted.

Comment: Will accept when it lets me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a UIImageView you can use Aspect Fill in the properties to do this.

But you may have to tick the box "Clip Subviews" otherwise the image will spill outside the image view frame.